# Flutter - TextField not autofocusing to the next TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, textfield

so imagine an OTP SMS verify code. i built this from custom text fields

[image]

it looks like this

i have focus nodes attached to each text field.

the idea is that every time you type a number in one of those text fields, the focus node autofocuses on the next text field

every time you type a number, the selection of that text field gets selected as you can see on the image

the problem is: if i select the "1" text field and type "1" again, it does not autofocus to the "2" text field. it just removes the selection like this

[image]

so if you type the same character that is highlighted by the selection, it just removes the selection. but if you type any other character then it autofocuses to the next input field

on my text field this is how i handle autofocus:

```dart
onChanged: (String value) {
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(previousFocusNode);
  } else {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocusNode);
  }
},
```

And this is how i handle auto selection when the text field gets selected:

```dart
controller.selection = TextSelection(
  baseOffset: 0,
  extentOffset: controller.text.length,
);
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: can you share the widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh what widget?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh you can try it for yourself. I think this is a general flutter bug. make 3 text fields with maximum input of 1 length and each time you type 1 character it's supposed to auto focus on the next text field. this works only if the next character you type is not the same character that was already typed in

Answer (score 0):

check this logic , you can style those ui i believe.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AutoFocusChangeOnSameChar extends StatefulWidget {
  AutoFocusChangeOnSameChar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AutoFocusChangeOnSameCharState createState() =>
      _AutoFocusChangeOnSameCharState();
}

class _AutoFocusChangeOnSameCharState extends State<AutoFocusChangeOnSameChar> {
  late FocusNode text1, text2, text3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    text1 = FocusNode();
    text2 = FocusNode();
    text3 = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    text1.dispose();
    text2.dispose();
    text3.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: text1,
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.length > 0) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(text2);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: text2,
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.length > 0) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(text3);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: text3,
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.length > 0) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```